# JavaFX resize elements automatically with window

Tags: javafx, resize, javafx-8

I'm trying to make components resize to keep their starting ratio depending on the size of the window.

Using an AnchorPane I can set the constraints to be in pixels, the problem is that resizing the window to make it bigger makes all the elements stretch to keep the exact same amount of pixels defined in the constraints.

What I want to be able to do is define them in terms of percentages or in some other way in order to keep the aspect ratio and position consistent between window sizes.

So far I've seen two possible solutions:

**Compute constraints on the fly**

Compute the constraints on each resize event as proposed in this question:
  [AnchorPane Constraints in percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172228/anchorpane-constraints-in-percentages#answer-24211863), but that means that piece of code could be potentially called once every pixel change.

**Nest Panes and surround the element with rows/columns**

Another way is to nest panes and components, something like:

Root > AnchorPane > GridPane > AnchorPane > Component

Now to position it where you want you add one row above, one below, one column before and one after where your component should be (surrounding it) and set the resize percentage of them.

This works by "leaking" the resizing behavior of the AnchorPane to the Component, and the width/height weight of the rows/columns.

My question is: **Is there a better way to do this?**

While both could work, none of them seem quite right. One involves calling code once every pixel change and the other one adds (*a lot of*) unused elements.

[Example using the second approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFMCt.png)